# Django - <FieldFile: None> While Updating a row in Employee table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am facing a problem while updating an employee data.

I want to update an already existed employee data. All the records are updated except Resume Field. When I tried to have a look at database, I found ***FileField:None* but all other fields are populated as expected.**

Where am I wrong?

> models.py

```
class employee_data(models.Model):
    eid=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    f_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    l_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.URLField(unique=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    passwd=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    jobarea=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    exp=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    current_job=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    skills=models.TextField(null=True)
    logincount=models.IntegerField()
    resume=models.FileField(upload_to='resume/%Y/%m/%d',null=True)
```

> views.py:

```
def reg_emp_done(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    uid=request.POST['id']
    if 'cv' in request.FILES:
        form=regform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            user=employee_data.objects.get(eid=uid)
            user.username=request.POST['uname']
            user.location=request.POST['location']
            user.gender=request.POST['gender']
            user.mobile=request.POST['mob']
            user.jobarea=request.POST['jobarea']
            user.exp=request.POST['exp']
            user.current_job=request.POST['current']
            user.skills=request.POST['skills']
            user.logincount=user.logincount+1
            user.resumefile=request.FILES['cv']
            user.save()
            return render_to_response('reg_done.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form=regform()
            return render_to_response('reg_emp.html',{'msg':'Sorry! Invalid Form','uid':uid},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form=regform()
        return render_to_response('reg_emp.html',{'msg':'Sorry! Resume file is Empty','uid':uid},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form=regform()
    return render_to_response('reg_emp.html',{'msg':'Sorry! Invalid Request, Start over'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

> forms.py:

```
class regform(forms.Form):
    eid=forms.IntegerField()
    f_name=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    l_name=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=forms.URLField()
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    passwd=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    location=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender=forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    mobile=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    jobarea=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    exp=forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    current_job=forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills=forms.CharField()
    logincount=forms.IntegerField()
    resume=forms.FileField()
```

> settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/Desktop/ojp/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 1):

can you show your template (.html) too? did you put enctype to your form?

```
form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Yup I did that as well.